# Bitmap cannot properly decode the byteArray which represents data from a file

Tags: java, android, arrays, bitmap

I've the following code:

```
File file = new File(filepath);
byte[] fileData = new byte[(int) file.length()];
DataInputStream dis = null;
try {
    dis = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
    dis.readFully(fileData);
    dis.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
    }

Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(fileData,0, fileData.length);
```

I succesfully manage to fill fileData with bytes, although to be honest I think there are too few bytes to represent the content of the jpg file referenced by filepath. But as even if I set it to have more bytes they are left as 0, I guess it contains the proper bytes.

But once the last instruction is executed bm is left as null.

What could I do so I can properly get the bitmap from that data?

PD: I'm aware it would be more logical to do:

```
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);
```

But, for some reason, that also returns null, so I'm taking this less direct approach to try to solve the issue.

After some investigation, I've checked that problem is that just a few bytes are the one being retrieved, with that, it's no brainer bitmpa ends up being null, what could I do so I get all bytes?

Comment: "But, for some reason, that also returns null" -- where are you getting `filepath` from? Either it is not a filesystem path, you do not have read access to the file, or the file is not a valid image.

Comment: @CommonsWare, file is from internal path like /data/data/packageName of the same application/files/filename.jpg, I think I should have read access there I can guarantee file is a valid image. Also, if it couldn't be read wouldn't it be able to read even one byte from the file?

Comment: "I can guarantee file is a valid image" -- `BitmapFactory` seems to disagree with you.

Comment: Got to find the reason thanks to your tip, if file is put in /data/data/packageName of the same application/ directory it can be succesfully read, anyway I wonder why I cannot in files. And by guarantee, I mean that with Android Studio device explorer I can open the image and it displays well, so there's no reason it's invalid mid execution.